# Data structure for finding an element with closest index value to x that is also greater than x

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

Given a file with integers to be read in one line at a time (one integer at a time), what is the most efficient method/ data structure for finding the element that is closest to x (by line or index both equivalent in this case) that has a value greater than or equal to x.
Ex. if sequence of numbers were read in as follows: 3,5,8,6,2,3,4 and the next value was to be 5 what is the most efficient data structure and implementation to determine that the closest value that's greater than or equal to 5 is 6?

Comment: If your sequence is `3,5,8,6,2,3,4`, why isn't 5 the closest value that's greater than or equal to 5?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a complex data structure. All you need is the variable `minimum` that has the given value (5 in your case) and a variable `closest` that will have the result *so far*.

When you start, that `closest` variable will need to be some predefined value that is extremely large. For instance, if you work with floating point data type, you can use *infinity* as an initial value.

Then, if ever you encounter an input value that is not less than `minimum`, but is less than `closest`, update the variable `closest` so it becomes equal to that input value.

After doing that for all input values, `closest` will have the desired value.